Pre-Zimri, could Pinchas eat the parts of kodshim kalim reserved for Kohanim?
According to the opinion that Pinchas became a Kohen at the end of the 40 years in the desert, was he allowed to eat the Kohen parts of kodshim kalim before that time?
A Kohen's daughter is allowed to eat kodshim kalim through her father, unless she's a chalalah or zonah.  A Kohen's son is typically either a Kohen himself and can eat them in his own right, or is a chalal and is not allowed to.
Pinchas was neither.  Could he eat kodshim kalim with his sisters, based on either ויליד ביתו or כל-טהור בביתך?
(Or terumah, but there was no terumah then.)

If you say that he was able to eat, then seemingly all of Moshe's descendants should be able to eat, according to the opinion that Moshe himself remained a Kohen.

@User123 maybe, or maybe just his kids would count as יליד ביתו but not future generations

There could be some IVF nafka minos somewhere here

What age was pinchas when Aaron got Kehuna? If he was already out of the house I.e married and not under his father then seemingly he would not have had any right to regardless

Pinchas' status before kehunah was weaker than that of a kohen with removable blemish. The kohen is יליד ביתו.

To answer the question, we need to find if Pinchas stayed in mahaneh Kehunah or mahaneh Leviyah.

@YDJ A kohen with a blemish, even nonremovable, is fully a kohen. He can even eat kodshei kodshim, not through his father as יליד ביתו, but in his own right.  He just can't do the avodah.

@Dude his sisters weren't kohanim either, but we know they could eat.

It seems that he wasn't allowed to eat anything that was meant to be eaten by a כהן. He wasn't a כהן till later. A כהן with a מום still has קדושת כהונה and that's why he can eat קדשים ותרומה. It would be a big חידוש to say that he would come under the category of יליד בית. However, as a לוי he would be able to receive מעשר ראשון (if that would have existed then).
I have seen quoted ספר מי זהב from the Zohar that a reason why Pinchas wasn't a כהן earlier was so that he could kill Zimri without having to worry about defiling his קדושת כהונה. That also implies that he had no דינים of a כהן at all.

It would be a big חידוש to say that he would come under the category of יליד בית. So it's a big חידוש to you — but is it correct?

Since it is a big חידוש, the onus is on you to bring a proof

The OP suggested the idea and isn't bringing it as an answer. If you're rejecting it, you should bring more than "I've never heard that argument before".
